# Best practice for defining a null index

Tags: c++, c

I often have to write methods that return an index into an array where there's a chance that no index will be found. There's three basic approaches that I've used:

1. Define a "null index" value as a negative number (i.e. if the
   function returns -1 it means there is no valid index to return
2. Define a "null index" value as the max for the type of the index
   (i.e. the function returns INT_MAX if the index is an int).
3. Pass in a pointer to a boolean that indicates whether the return
   value is a valid index (i.e. pass in a pointer to a boolean that is
   set to true if the return value is an actual index in the array,
   otherwise the return value is false)

I've seen all these approaches used (although the 3rd option seems to crop up a lot less). Is there any consensus as to which one of these is preferable (or is there a 4th option)?

Comment: perfect use case for [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) imho (p.s: I'm pretty sure there will be an `std::optional` in C++14, so this approach is "future proof")

Comment: Only #1 isn't unusual from the 3 options and as an array can never have a negative array index in c or c++, there seems to be no reason not to use it.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed for being opinion-based because the question is "Is there any consensus (...) Or is there a 4th option?".

Comment: boost::optional might be heavy-handed depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on boost::optional. It seems to have been designed exactly for this purpose. I also agree that it feels a little like hunting squirrel with a Tomahawk missile but that's because most of the time I'm using raw arrays is in low level bits of code where this amount of overhead wouldn't make sense. In other situations though it might be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt: copy the STL. For example std::string::npos, std::vector::end(), etc. I guess that would be option 2 in your list.

Containers that work like STL containers can also reuse STL algorithms.

Comment: With respect to C++, this also calls into question whether the OP should be using an array or an STL container. As indicated in the C++ FAQ, array usage in C++ is [generally discouraged](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html).

Comment: @DavidRR, I was assuming the question meant array as a stand-in for some special purpose container, not literally an array. But on second reading, you're right, a better answer to this question is: stop using native arrays.

Comment: Since the OP included the `C` tag with his question, we might have to assume that arrays may not be entirely avoidable in his situation. But with respect to C++, arrays should generally be avoided to the extent possible.

Comment: I generally do use vectors but there's a few scenarios where it doesn't make sense. Just to list a few: 1) I need to use C; 2) I need to guarantee that the contents of the array are not going to move around in memory; 3) I'm dealing with relatively short lists of POD objects and need to serialize them frequently and trivially; 4) I have lots of objects that contain lots of short lists and performance is a requirement so I don't want the overhead of vectors that only contain a handful of tiny items.

Answer (score 2):

#4. Return the negative of the nearest lower index, i.e. the insertion point. Add 1 first so you don't have to worry about -0. So any negative result is 'not found', *and* you can get an insertion point from it if you need it in the next operation.

Answer (score 1):

Since the index into an array is generally a non-negative integer, returning a negative integer (e.g., `-1`) to indicate a *non-valid* index is an acceptable approach.

Comment: Except you throw away half your possible indices.

Comment: @Adam - It depends on the use case. Here is a [nice example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133853/1497596) that shows how a negative index can be properly used. However, I am guessing that the situation that the OP is describing does not call for the use of negative index values.

Comment: @AdamBurry: This ought only to be a problem for `char` arrays. If you're on a 32 bit machine, for instance, you ought to have at least a 32 bit signed integer type, and for any array with elements of two bytes or more you're going to run out of addressable memory before you run out of available indices. And if you have a single `char` array taking up half your available memory, then you deserve to run out of indices for making it that way in the first place.

Comment: @Adam - The answer I referenced shows a valid use of a negative index. However, that doesn't necessarily mean that such a use is common in practice. And its generally a good idea to avoid 'tricks' in code when more routine approaches are possible. When an unusual coding approach is justifiable and its intent is not clear, it should be adequately commented.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique that is useful in some cases is to use 1 .. N as your index, and have your NULL index be 0, so you can pull some sort of default from the 0th element, or accumulated into the 0th element.   That way in your caller, you don't actually have to check to see if you got the NULL index.

Answer (score 1):

Does nobody remember `errno`? I'd argue this is a reasonable solution. If the function returns a certain value such as 0 (since we are talking about array indices) and `errno == ERANGE`, an invalid index is returned:

```
idx =foo.bar(baz);
if (!idx && errno == ERANGE) {
    // problem
}
```

Arguably, you don't even need to set a value since you would need to check `errno` anyway.

This way, you have full use of the array. The other approach is a variation of this, which is already a variation of the Boolean value approach: use a class-local error variable, similar to I/O errors that set badbit, failbit and/or eofbit. If you aren't using a class, then I'd say `errno`/the Boolean approach is the best.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I would say #4:

- Return a status code indicating whether the operation succeeded or failed and return the index by reference (either using references or a pointer depending on your version of C).

The advantages of #4 over #3 are:

1. When you need a function to return more than one value, just add more reference parameters for the values you need to return.
2. If your C functions always return status codes everywhere in your program, then you always know that the return code is status.
3. It does not eat into your value space for the return index (or other data types) that your function returns and avoids magic number constants.  (For example, if you were returning a temperature value in Celsius, 0 and -1 are both valid as are any positive numbers.  You might return -274 as invalid, but that is a little obtuse.)
4. The return code can give a reason for failure or success more than just a Boolean success or failure in a pretty straightforward way.

OTOH, if you program is pretty small, and you don't mind a few magic constants, then either #1 or #2 are morally equivalent and can make for less typing than #3 or #4.  #2 has a few advantages over #1:

1. As mentioned in other answers, a signed int return value can only represent half of the numbers an unsigned int can represent.
2. It avoids signed vs. unsigned comparison issues if you are comparing against sizeof(array), std::vector::string, which are size_t.  Most often the issue is a compiler warning gets ignored (leading people to generally ignore warnings when they should not) or someone fixes it with a cast, hopefully after analyzing to make sure that the cast is really valid.

I have personally used #1, #2, and #4 and find the #4 scales the best.  I tend to default to #4, especially in code where failures are common and need to be handled.  Either 1 or 2 usually work out best if the code is smaller and you are calling a lot of routines that return one thing and cannot fail (e.g., image processing routines).

Answer (score 0):

The best "null index" is one that matches the null model.  That is an index that doesn't exist at all.

To pull it off, you typically throw an exception.

Comment: Throwing an exception when it is something that you expect will happen quite often, that does not sound optimal.

Comment: Exceptions are generally used for exceptional situations. The semantics of the return value in the OP's question is 'not found'. I agree with @Simon; I don't believe this situation calls for throwing an exception.

Comment: Personally, asking for the index of something that doesn't exist isn't what I would call "something that I expect will happen quite often", but there are programmers who would argue otherwise.

Comment: @Edwin - How about [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)? The purpose of both of those functions is to search for a value in a container. Each returns a special value to indicate when a match has not been found.

Comment: std::find and string::find mix control and data into the same return output.  Yes, there is a long history of doing so, and coming from C's background, it would probably be quite foreign to do it in another way; however, it is far from an ideal.  Other libraries use the equivalent of ::contains for returning back if it is contained, instead of mixing in a special control character.