# Can a character in C ever be both a newline and a NULL terminator?

Tags: c, string

1. What is the purpose of `if (cmdline[-1] == '\n' && cmdline[-1] == '\0')` in the following code sample?

   - when will this ever evaluate to true?
2. How does the negative index in `cmdline[-1]` work here? I've seen similar questions on SO, but here there's no pointer arithmetic beforehand.

Here's the pseudocode it comes from:

```
parseInfo *parse (char *cmdline) {
  parseInfo *Result;
  char command[MAXLINE];
  int com_pos = -1;

  if (cmdline[-1] == '\n' && cmdline[-1] == '\0')
    return NULL;

  Result = malloc(sizeof(parseInfo));
  init_info(Result);
  com_pos=0;
  /*  while (cmdline[i] != '\n' && cmdline[i] != '\0') { */

  command[com_pos]='\0';
  parse_command(command, 0); /* &Result->CommArray[Result->pipeNum]);*/

  return Result;
}
```

EDIT #1:
Why does "When does this NOT get printed?" get printed in the following situation:
EDIT #2: I made `cmdline` a valid string by increasing the length by 1 (include the null character) and by copying `length` bytes into `length` malloc'd ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse(char *cmdline) {
  printf("'%c'\n", cmdline[-1]);
  if (cmdline[-1] == '\0' || cmdline[-1] == '\n') {
    printf("When does this NOT get printed?\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  char str[100] = "hello";
  const int length = strlen(str) + 1;
  char *cmdline = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
  strncpy(cmdline, str, length);
  parse(cmdline);
  return 0;
}
```

With the corresponding output:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
$ gcc negative_index.c
$ ./a.out
''
When does this NOT get printed?
```

Comment: `cmdline[-1] == '\n' && cmdline[-1] == '\0'` always false.

Comment: I suppose it was meant to be `||` and not `&&`?

Comment: You better think about what a negative array index will do. (Hint: Array indexes are usually `size_t` which is commonly the same as `unsigned long`, what is `-1` as an `unsinged long`?)

Comment: and keep in mind: "Accessing an array beyond its bounds results in Undefined Behavior(UB)" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133804/negative-array-index-in-c).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `cmdline[-1]` is the same as `*((cmdline)+(-1))`. If that's not well-defined, then how could you ever subtract from a pointer? Does the `--` operator produce UB too?

Comment: … also, `ptrdiff_t`, which is always signed, would be a better match.

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. The null *character* `'\0'` is a different thing.

Comment: Technically, this *can* evaluate to `TRUE`: the actual values of alphabetic escape sequences are implementation-defined to support non-ASCII systems. So, technically, it *could* be possible for `\0` and `\n` to have the same value, if I am reading the standard correctly...

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the responses. per question 1, I agree with @BloodShura that it was probably just a typo.

Comment: re: question 2, I'm still don't understand why someone would check cmdline[-1] against those two values?. In my case, the string is read in from the `readline` library and then is passed into the `parse` function. There is no pointer arithmetic before the call to `parse`.

Comment: In your last edit, you are invoking Underined Behavior because you cannot safely copy 6 bytes into the 5 malloc'ed ones. Even 5 is not correct -- the reult is not a valid C string.

Comment: @Jongware, I increased the length by one and fixed cmdline by only copying 6 bytes into 6 malloc'd ones. Now that `cmdline` is valid, is this still UB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, a `char` can NOT be both `\n` and `\0`, the code perhaps meant
   to use `||` instead of `&&`.
2. For example:

   ```
   char str[100] = "hello world";
   char *cmdline = str + 10;
   ```

   Then `cmdline[-1]` is the same as `str[9]`.

Comment: I'm in agreement on #1; but that isn't what cmdline is set too for #2. See my edit in the question for clarification.